# Open Website as Project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open existing files that were previously opened as a project in Visual Studio, but I moved them and renamed the folder. How can I open these files in Visual Studio as a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by website project. If its the solution files you want then way I found worked for me.

However, If its the project files that add DLL's to your site you will need to create a new project of the same type and copy your code in that project. But the Project file that opens these should still work if it was copied over with the other files.

To add an existing folder to a Solution: Open the the folder as a new website. Ensure that any old .sln files are deleted from the new folder.

When you attempt to close Visual Studios it should prompt you to save your site in a new solution(.sln) file